# How should I mount external hardware to a Greenboard/EPS exterior wall?

Tags: insulation, hardware, sheathing

The external cladding of my house is rendered NRG Greenboard (an EPS product). What is the best way to mount simple external hardware (specifcally, a hose reel) to this material?

The reel itself just came with 4 screws that are meant to affix it to the external wall of the house, but it seems like with the EPS it wouldn't take much force at all to yank them straight out. What's the recommended procedure for mounting things securely to the EPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NRG greenboard](http://www.nrggreenboard.com/sites/default/files/NRG_Greenboard_Technical_Specification_Booklet_Version_6-1_0.pdf) is ***98% air and therefore only 2% polystyrene***

NOTHING can be mounted TO this.  Your reel may be mounted THROUGH it to the studs behind.

> > From the Greenboard handbook:
> >
> > 17.1.5 Solid Blocking of Fitting and Accessories
> >     Consideration should be given to the installation of 
> >     wall mounted accessories i.e. taps, electrical fittings, 
> >     etc. It is important to allow for adequate backblocking for these items prior to the 
> >     installation of the NRG Greenboard™.

Since this didn't happen, you have to add the blocking EXTERNALLY.

The typical 50' hose full of water is at least 15 pounds, the reel another 10 pounds and the pulling on the hose another 25 pounds or more, so you need a sturdy solution.

You would do well to distribute this across 2 studs, perhaps using 2 2x4 treated lumber.  The screws would need to be long enough to go through the boards, outer covering (I hope the house isn't only covered in greenboard), the green board and at least 1" into the stud.  Weather proof decking screws (ceramic coated for rust) would be a sturdy choice and come in 3", 3 1/2" and 4" lengths.  All screw holes should be pilot drilled and filled with an exterior caulk or an exterior silicone.

Once the support boards are mounted to the studs, the reel can be attached to the boards with the original hardware.

[image]

Comment: +1 Like the diagram - especially the round headed deck screws.

Comment: Special screws, down under, mate. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  I suppose another possible solution would be to fix a couple of posts in the ground, mount the 2x4's between them, and secure the reel onto that?

Comment: Sure, you could mount the hose reel on a post instead of directly on the house. A single 4x4 post should be more than adequate if properly set in concrete.

Comment: @aroth The posts idea is a good one, +1